# Windows Phone PopUp disable back window

Tags: winforms, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a simple PopUp window in my Windows Phone app, which takes another window as a child:

```
    private static MeterChangeDialog_Popup _instance = null;
    private static Popup _meterchangepop;
    private MeterChangeDialog_Popup()
    {
        _meterchangepop = new Popup();
    }

    public static MeterChangeDialog_Popup GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new MeterChangeDialog_Popup();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
    public void OpenClosePopup()
    {
        if (_meterchangepop.IsOpen)
        {
            _meterchangepop.IsOpen = false;

            SingletonContainer.GetInstance().MeterChangeCurrentSelected = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _meterchangepop.IsOpen = true;
            _meterchangepop.Child = new MeterChangePage();
        }
    }
```

But while this window is open, I can still do stuff at the window behind it, which I should not be able to do. 
Can I somehow disable every window behind the PopUp window ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the main pop up ?

Comment: The main popup ? There will only be this '_meterchangepop' as a pop up in this case. But it will "pop" over another window. And I want to "disable" this window, so the user only can interact with the pop up window.